# customize paypal button using css or html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal

Why can't I wrap my button like this? The button did not appear when I do extra stuff with it.

```
<div>
  <div id="paypal-button"></div>
</div>
```

How do I position it? [This doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-button/#paypal-button-brand-guidelines) has very limited information.

Comment: The question is too generic. Relax & tell us where & what exactly is your issue with some more code.

Comment: Do you have add this script? `<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>`

Comment: after I add it within `<head>` then it worked ><

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can not load the button because: or you don't have put the script or you have wrong something when you write your script.

For work the 
`<div> <div id="paypal-button"></div> </div>` need have two script.

To include the checkout.js script, add this line on the page where you want to render the PayPal button or in the header it's ok:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>
```

after use `<div id="paypal-button"></div>` to create a container element for the PayPal button.

also you need to render the button, try to add this code in the page where is the button are in the header.

```
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'production', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment

        payment: function() {
            // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here, when the buyer approves the transaction
       }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

In this way you will see the button.